# How do I get the data from a Select2 options/value (tags) to the controller in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to use Select2 for editing tags for an article. My problem is, that the Tags field in my viewmodel is null when returned to the controller.

An ArticleTag has an Id and a Name field.

**ViewModel**

```
public class EditArticleViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
    [UIHint("TagsEditor")]
    public IList<ArticleTag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**EditArticle view**

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tags)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})       
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tags')
        .select2({
            data: ["Clare", "Cork", "South Dublin"],
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [','],
            placeholder: "Add your tags here"
        });
</script>
```

**Editor template**

```
@model List<MVCForum.Domain.DomainModel.CMS.ArticleTag>
<select id="tags" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{       
    <option selected="selected">@Model[i].Name</option>
}
</select>
```

Now I just can't figure out how to get the data from my Editortemplate/View to the Controller. The List is null when returned.

I have tried to change it to a list of strings instead (in the viewmodel, editortemplate and so on). I have tried to add an editortemplate for the Name field. Same result.

The best thing for me would actually be to get the tags as a comma seperated string. But I just wan't it to work somehow.

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects - you need a property (say) `int[] SelectedTags` to bind to (assuming you want to post back the `Id`'s of the  selected `Tags`). And replace you `EditorTemplate` with `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, new SelectList(Model.Tags, "Id", "Name")` and then `$('#SelectedTags').select2() {...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okay, so I will change it back to a list of strings in the viewmodel, and use the @Html.ListBoxFor. But, I don't fully understand what you mean with "and then $('#SelectedTags').‌​select2() {...".

Comment: A `<select multiple>` posts back an array of simple values (`string`, `int` etc), not a array of complex objects. I don't know if you want to bind to the `Id` or the `Name` value of `ArticleTag` but your view model needs an array of matching simple values (`string[]` or `int[]`) to bind to. I suggested that be named `SelectedTags` so the `id` of your control is `SelectedTags` which is why it needs to be `$('#SelectedTags').‌​select2() {...`. And why are you manually overriding the values using `data: ....`?

Comment: Should it be an array, or can it be a List<string>?
"data:" is the autocomplete data, I havent gotten to that part yet.

Comment: Either `List<string>` or `string[]`

Comment: Okay, so now I have a List<string> in the viewmodel.
Do I then use @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Tags, new SelectList(Model.Tags), new {@id = "tags", @style="width: 100%"}) in my EditArticle view? (and skip all editortemplate)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121113/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-asger-vestbjerg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<select multiple>` posts back an array of simple values, not complex objects, so you cannot bind to property `IList<ArticleTag> Tags`. Your view model should contain a property to bind to and a property for the options (the following assumes you want to post back the `Name` property of each selected `ArticleTag`).

```
public class EditArticleViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ....
    [Display(Name = "Tags")]
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedTags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TagsList { get; set; }
}
```

Your GET method would then be

```
var tags = db.ArticleTag.Select(x => x.Name);
var model = new EditArticleViewModel()
{
     TagsList = new SelectList(tags),
     SelectedTags = ... // set values to be selected initially if required
};
return View(model);
```

Then remove your `EditorTemplate` and replace it with the strongly typed `ListBoxFor()` method so that it binds to your model properties

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, Model.TagsList)
```

and modify the script to use the `id` attribute generated by the `ListBoxFor()` method

```
$('#SelectedTags').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    placeholder: "Add your tags here"
});
```

Comment: Hi Stephen do you know how I can implement this where the tags comes from a list of objects with 2 string properties? 1 for the display name and 1 for the value?

Comment: @Bassie, Not sure I understand - are you wanting to display the (say) `Name` property of your objects but post back the associated `Id` of the selected objects?

Comment: I actually found a solution to this. What I was looking for is: `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, new SelectList(users, "UserName", "DisplayName"))` so the tags use `DisplayName` property to show the user, but the string values which get submitted come from the `UserName` property

Comment: @Bassie - As a side note, best practice is that the `users` property should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not `IEnumerable<yourObject>`) so its just `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, users)` in the view